# Beautiful Soup is not filtering values

Tags: python, python-3.x, odoo

hii all here i have a code snippet in which i am using beautiful soup to parse value

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(self.content, 'html.parser')
count = 1
for assumptions in data_list:
    for rec in soup.findAll():
        if (assumptions.replace(' ', '') in rec.get_text().replace(' ', '') or (assumptions.replace(' ', '') == rec.get_text().replace(' ', ''))
            if assumptions in data_list:
                data_list.remove(assumptions)
                count += 1
```

Here in `self.content` field I am getting the `HTML data`,

`data_list` is a list of strings

I am searching those strings which are available in the data_list inside the HTML content which is partially working.

some strings that I am searching for are avaliable in HTMl content but still, I am unable to process those in the `if condition`.

What will be the `if condition` in which I can parse all the strings which are inside the data_list

Comment: You shouldn't modify a list while you're iterating over it.

Comment: Am I misreading, or are both conditions in the `or` the same?

Comment: No actually its not the same @Barmar.. if i have done `===` then it will be same.... Anyway if i remove the if statement also its skipped the value

Comment: Then can you please suggest me the condition.. because every time i parse its misses some strings..

Comment: If two strings are equal, then one is also in the other. You don't need both conditions, `in` is enough.

Comment: As explained, the problem isn't the condition, it's because you're modifying the list while you loop over it. So it skips some elements.

Comment: `data_list = [assumptions for assumptions in data_list if assumptions.replace(' ', '') not in soup.get_text().replace(' ', '')]`

Comment: There's no need to loop over `findAll()` since the text of soup is the concatenation of the text of all its elements.